# Compute the following triple integral on an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\int\int\int_{E}{|xyz|dxdydz}$ Where $E=\{(x,y,z)|\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leq1\}$

So I used a linear operator $(x,y,z) \to (ax,by,cz)$ to turn the ellipsoid E to $B$ (the unit ball) and now the integral I need to compute is $a^2b^2c^2\int\int\int_{B}{|xyz|dxdydz}$.
Then I switched to spherical coordinates and got $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}{|r^3cos\varphi sin\varphi\sin^2\theta\cos\theta|r^2sin\theta \ drd\theta d\varphi}$=

$\frac{(abc)^2}{6}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{|cos\varphi sin\varphi\cos\theta|sin^3\theta\ d\theta d\varphi}$

I dont know how to deal with the integral thats left.. Any help?

Comment: You did the hard part. One key word: SYMMETRY. Alternatively, how would you do an integral like $\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin x|\,dx$?

Comment: Your integrand attains same value on all symmetries against axes and the origin. So from the beginning only compute on the positive 1/8th coordinates, and then multiply by 8.

Comment: Ok, that helps eliminate the absolute value but I'm still left with a rather "ugly" integral here: $\frac{8(abc)^2}{6}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{cos\varphi sin\varphi\cos\theta sin^3\theta\ d\theta d\varphi}$ What would you do next?

Comment: As for the $\phi$-integral I'd do two integrations by part, and then isolate the answer in the equation you get. In the $\theta $-integral I'd substitute $t = \sin(\theta)$.

EDIT: I'd substitute $t=\sin(\phi)$ in the first integral too btw ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres some detailed calculations:

\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)d\phi = \int_0^1 t dt = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
here I've made the substitution $t = \sin(\phi) $ ($dt= \cos(\phi)d\phi$).

\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)d\theta = \int_0^1 t^3 dt = \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}
Here I made the substitution $t = \sin(\theta)$.